# Check XMM register for all zeroes

Tags: c++, sse, simd, intrinsics

Is there a way to check if all bits/bytes/words etc. in a `__m128i` variable are 0?
In my app I have to check if all integers packed in a in a `__m128i` variable are zeroes. Will I have to extract them and compare each separately?

---

Edit:

What I am doing now is:

```
int next = 0;
do{
    //some code

    next = idata.m128i_i32[0] + idata.m128i_i32[1] + idata.m128i_i32[2] + idata.m128i_i32[3];
}while(next > 0);
```

What I need is to check if `idata` is all zeroes without having to access each individual element, and quit the loop if they are...

---

Based on Harold's comment this is the solution:

```
__m128i idata = _mm_setr_epi32(i,j,k,l);
do{
    //some code
}while( !_mm_testz_si128(idata, idata) );
```

This will exit the loop if all low bits of each DW in `idata` are 0... thanks harold!

Comment: Can't you use, say, `PCMPEQD` to compare without extraction?

Comment: Do XMM registers have a flag register attached to them? If yes, there must be a zero flag among these bits.

Comment: See `PTEST` is SSE4 available, otherwise it take slightly more effort.

Comment: You don't need to initialise a dummy argument for the second parameter of `PTEST`, i.e. instead of `_mm_testz_si128(idata, _mm_set1_epi32(0xFFFF))` you can just do `_mm_testz_si128(idata, idata)`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/27905677/ which has some interesting commentary and alternate (possibly faster) answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is an \_\_m128i variable zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989897/is-an-m128i-variable-zero)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

_mm_testz_si128 is SSE4.1 which isn't supported on some CPUs (e.g. Intel Atom, AMD Phenom)

Here is an SSE2-compatible variant

```
inline bool isAllZeros(__m128i xmm) {
    return _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_cmpeq_epi8(xmm, _mm_setzero_si128())) == 0xFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Like Paul R commented to my original post:

"You don't need to initialise a dummy argument for the second parameter of `PTEST`, i.e. instead of `_mm_testz_si128(idata, _mm_set1_epi32(0xFFFF))` you can just test a value against itself."

`ptest` does the entire job with one instruction.

This helped.