# SSE Intrinsics: Fastest way to test for all 0s or 1s?

Tags: c, windows, optimization, sse, intrinsics

I have developed a Mandelbrot generator for Windows which I have just converted to use SSE Intrinsics.  To detect the end of the iterations, in normal arithmetic I do a  greater than compare and break out.  Doing this in SSE I can do a compare of the whole vector using _mm_cmpgt_pd/_mm_cmpgt_ps however this will write a new 128-bit vector with all 1s for the case I care about.

My question is, is there a more efficient way of detecting for all 1s rather than checking the 2 packed 64 INTs?  Or if it is more efficient to detect for all 0s then I could compare for less than.  Here is what I currently have:

```
_m128d CompareResult = Magnitude > EarlyOut;
const __m128i Tmp = *reinterpret_cast< __m128i* >( &CompareResult );
if ( Tmp.m128i_u64[ 0 ] == Tmp.m128i_u64[ 1 ] == -1 )
{
    break;
}
```

The reason I want to find a better way is because I don't like the cast, but also because according to vTune over 30% of my iteration time is spent in this last line.  I know a lot of that will be in the branch itself, but I assume I can reduce this with a better detecting of 0s or 1s.

Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175711/check-xmm-register-for-all-zeroes

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're testing the result of a compare then you can just extract the MS bits of each byte as a 16 bit int and test this, e.g.

```
int mask = _mm_movemask_epi8((__m128i)CompareResult);
if (mask == 0xffff)
{
    // compare results are all "true"
}
```

Note that this is one example of a more general technique for SIMD predicates in SSE, i.e.

```
mask == 0xffff // all "true"
mask == 0x0000 // all "false"
mask != 0xffff // any "false"
mask != 0x0000 // any "true"
```

Comment: I think this is the most efficient solution also. Might need 0xFFFF in place of 0xFF when 128 bit data is used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I popped this in and it was very slightly slower than my original version.  Also, I still needed the ugly cast as my SSE variable type is __m128d although I made it into a const reference which saved some time too.

Comment: Note that the performance picture may vary on different CPUs and with different compilers, i.e. you might get a win in some cases but not in others, so if this is code for general distribution then you might want to benchmark with other CPUs if you can.

Comment: If you've got SSE4 (`PTEST`) then see the question linked to above.

Comment: @FrankH: `PTEST` is good for checking for all zeroes, but I'm not sure it helps with the all ones case ?

Comment: I'd think that _inverting your comparison_ would do that ?

Comment: @FrankH: unfortunately not - "not all bits equal to zero" is not the same as "all bits equal to one".

Comment: @PaulR: That's not what I meant. Instead of using `compareResult = (magnitude > earlyOut)` you can use `compareResult = (magnitude <= earlyOut)`. If the former is all ones, the latter is all zeroes.

Comment: @FrankH: I see what you mean - I was thinking more of the more general problem of testing for any/all 1s/0s, but you're right in the case of a compare.