# Equal zero instruction in SSE

Tags: c++, sse, avx

Suppose I have a 128-bit integer vector:

```
__m128i x;
```

Then how to know if all the bits in x are zeros?

Checking every packed integer is a simple approach.

But I'm looking for a faster way.

Is there any instruction in SSE can do this job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is SSE 4.1, you can use `_mm_testz_si128`, e.g.

```
_mm_testz_si128(idata, _mm_set1_epi32(0x0000))
```

Probably look also into [Check XMM register for all zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175711/check-xmm-register-for-all-zeroes) for a SSE2 compatible solution.

Comment: Note that you don't need to generate a zero vector for the second param, you can just pass `idata` for both.

Comment: Do you know how to do this for 256-bit float vector, that is , checking if all the bits in a 256-bit float vector are zero?@PaulR

Comment: @KUN come on, I am sure you can guess the name for 256 bits from the one for 128 bits...

Comment: As might be expected, you can just use the corresponding AVX intrinsic: `int _mm256_testz_ps (__m256 a, __m256 b)`. You might want to bookmark the [Intel intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) for future such questions.

Comment: But base on the description, _mm256_testz_ps (__m256 a, __m256 b) seems to check the sign bits after bitwise operation. What I want is checking all 256 bits.@PaulR

Comment: I was talking about _mm256_testz_si256...

Comment: My bad - I referenced `_mm256_testz_ps` when it should be `_mm256_testz_si128`.